# Max35Text length

Tags: finance, iso

In `ISO20022` `Pain.001.001.03` messages we have certain fields of type `Max35Text` such as `InstrId` which by defination

> Unique identification, as assigned by an instructing party for an
>   instructed party, to unambiguously identify the instruction.
>
> Data Type:  Max35Text, Format:  maxLength: 35, minLength: 1

the `maxLength` is 35, is that mean I cannot assign UUID to those fields of that type `Max35Text`?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "is that mean I cannot assign UUID to those fields of that type Max35Text?"

Comment: Are you really asking if 36 < 35? This question doesn't make much sense but if you are set on using uuid you could for instance skip the hyphens or encode it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UUID but please keep in mind the length must be not more than 35 characters. Please use UUID in format without "-" and it will match the requrements.